# Cannot convert workbook to sheet in NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, npoi

I use [NPOI 2.0.1 beta](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to import excel(xlsx) data to GridView .
Firstly , using [this link](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/read-xlsx-data-for-npoi/) , convert `xlsx Worksheet` format to `xls Worksheet` .
But , at the following line , it's show me error .

```
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
 HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);
```

And here is a screen-shoot ,

[image]

How can I fix it ?
Or is there a better way ? Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

In NPOI 2.0, you should use ISheet and IWorkbook interface.

ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");